# Is there a way of setting up a OPC UA Client on a ESP32 with MicroPython?

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

I am trying to connect a couple of sensors to an ESP32 and would like it to function as an OPC UA Client, talking to my server over the local network. However if I try to implement this in the main() file and try to flash it to the ESP, I get the message that there is no module named opcua.
As I understand it, not every python library is implemented in micropython but if at all possible I would like to try and implement it myself maybe?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [pure Python implementation](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua) of OPC UA but it's written against CPython, and references a bunch of modules which have no MicroPython counterpart. Theoretically this could be ported but it's going to be a lot of work. Alternative would be to take just the parts you need and rewrite them to work with MicroPython and/or provide basic implementations of the needed modules yourself. All in all: not the easiest task.